# How to solve Syntax error on token

Tags: java

I m trying to pass long value to the function.But Its says "**Syntax error on token "long", delete this token**".Please explain this what is this and when this kind of error is occure

Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Calendar currenttime = Calendar.getInstance();          
    Date date = currenttime.getTime();
    long timeInMillisSinceEpoch = date.getTime(); 
    long ctimeInMinutesSinceEpoch = timeInMillisSinceEpoch / 1000;              
    Calendar subhr = Calendar.getInstance();
    subhr.add(Calendar.HOUR, -1);              
    Date date1 = subhr.getTime();
    long timeInMillisSinceEpoch1 = date1.getTime(); 
    long btimeInMinutesSinceEpoch1 = timeInMillisSinceEpoch1 / 1000;
    //error on this line 
    printCSV(long btimeInMinutesSinceEpoch1,long ctimeInMinutesSinceEpoch); 
}

public static void printCSV(long bdata,long cdata) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(protocol + "://" + hostname + "/apiv2/csv.xml?username=" + userName + "&password=" + password + "&form_id=" + formId + "&begin_second="+bdata +"&end_second="+cdata);
        HttpURLConnection urlCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        System.out.println(urlCon);
    }
```

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 4):

Change `printCSV(long btimeInMinutesSinceEpoch1,long ctimeInMinutesSinceEpoch);`  to

```
printCSV(btimeInMinutesSinceEpoch1,ctimeInMinutesSinceEpoch);
```

You don't need to specify datatype of input parameters within function call while passing parameters to function.

Answer (score 2):

It's this line:

```
    //error on this line 
    printCSV(btimeInMinutesSinceEpoch1, ctimeInMinutesSinceEpoch);
```

Answer (score 1):

While calling a method you need NOT to specify the type of input parameters. Hence change this:

```
printCSV(long btimeInMinutesSinceEpoch1,long ctimeInMinutesSinceEpoch);
```

to

```
printCSV(btimeInMinutesSinceEpoch1,ctimeInMinutesSinceEpoch);
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
printCSV(btimeInMinutesSinceEpoch1, ctimeInMinutesSinceEpoch);
```

without `long`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   long btimeInMinutesSinceEpoch1 = timeInMillisSinceEpoch1 / 1000;
    long ctimeInMinutesSinceEpoch = timeInMillisSinceEpoch / 1000;
```

In the above 2 lines you have already declared `btimeInMinutesSinceEpoch1` and `ctimeInMinutesSinceEpoch` as long type.Now in this line     `printCSV(long btimeInMinutesSinceEpoch1,long ctimeInMinutesSinceEpoch);` 
you are again declaring the same thing
correct answer 
`printCSV(btimeInMinutesSinceEpoch1,ctimeInMinutesSinceEpoch);`